# Is the ssd faulty if its sequential read isnt upto the advertised-mark?

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, performance, pci-express

I have just brought a new WD SN550 500GB SSD and crystal disk mark 8's SEQ1M Q8T1's result for my SSD is around 1600 MB/s which is very low compared to 2400 MB/s as advertised by Western Digital, should I return my drive and replace with another one or this is normal? All remaining parameters of the benchmark including write speeds and random read speeds are performing up to the mark or in some cases even better, I am not able to understand what exactly is going on here!!!

Performance (mentioned on WD's Website) Sequential Read (MB/s) up to 2,400 Sequential Write (MB/s) up to 1,750 Random Read 4KB IOPS up to (Queues=32, Threads=16)- 250K Random Write 4KB IOPS up to (Queues=32, Threads=16)- 175K Endurance (TBW)- 300

Performance seen Sequential Read (MB/s) up to 1,600 Sequential Write (MB/s) up to 1,880 Random Read 4KB IOPS up to (Queues=32, Threads=16)- 255k Random Write 4KB IOPS up to (Queues=32, Threads=16)- 160k Endurance (TBW)- 300

any help would be very appreciated. Thanks!!!

Comment: Is your motherboard definitely connecting at Gen3 x4? ~2GB/s could be an x2 connection and could mean your motherboard is the problem and returning it wouldn't change that.

Comment: @Mokubai how do I check if it's Gen3 x4 or x2 because the SSD that came with the laptop preinstalled is giving read and write speeds of approx 3000 MB/s so is I am assuming that all other PCI-E slots offer the same speeds.

Comment: Not all slots are equal. Some motherboards have BIOS settings to change second slot link speeds so that other devices can share bandwidth so you may have to check there. https://i.stack.imgur.com/XqHDA.jpg (from https://uk.crucial.com/support/articles-faq-ssd/bios-uefi-configuration-optimizing-m2) Or it could be a limitation of your motherboard for the second slot. Just because one NVME drive operates at full speed does not automatically mean that all other links on your motherboard are set up the same. You should check your motherboard manual.

Comment: I'm actually suspecting the M.2 slot is PCIe 2.0 x4, rather than PCIe 3.0 x2. It's unusual for a motherboard M.2 slot to have only two PCIe lanes.